# just_audio not working on ios flutter Unhandled Exception: (-11800) The operation could not be completed

Tags: ios, flutter, file, audio, just-audio

I am trying to run the just_audio sample project from its own repository https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/tree/master/just_audio/example

It is working fine on android but when I clone the project using a mac and run it on the simulator it throws this error :

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: (-11800) The operation could not be completed 
    #0      AudioPlayer._load (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:778:9)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #1      AudioPlayer._setPlatformActive.<anonymous closure> (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:1346:28)
    <asynchronous suspension>
```

And this error pops up while I'm trying to call the audio URL for streaming using setUrl() method

I have also tried Editing Transport security as the documentation recommends

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

**Note**

I have tried all the other packages available for ios for playing and streaming audio and none of them worked

Comment: And double check the asset url.



mediaItem: MediaItem(
            ...
            extras: {'url': 'asset:///assets/audios/count_1.mp3'})

Comment: Hi, did you solved the problem? I'm facing exact same problem.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I restarted the IOS simulator and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Try this solution first, did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to connect to non-HTTPS URLS, add the following to your Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Still not working :( throws the same error

Answer (score 2):

You might need to test `just_audio` on a **real iOS device**.

It seems like the exception only gets thrown on a Simulator.

---

Also, don't forget to allow arbitrary loads as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69786327/9635809) by [Reham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14715874/reham-alraee)

Comment: Thanks but this issue was on both simulator and real device, I solved it btw. the issue was because I was using a signed URL generated by AWS with a security level on top of it. So It did not contain the audio extension in the URL itself. as soon as I add the extension to the URL , problem solved.

Comment: could your tell me how to add audio extension in URL itself, pleas

Comment: Just wanted to add that for me it works even on **iOS Simulator**. (my issue was with `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error was that I had configured bitRate equal to `25600`, when I changed it to `32000`, it worked correctly.

```
record.start(
    path: 'pathTo/file/audio.m4a',
    encoder: AudioEncoder.aacLc,
    bitRate: 25600, // <-- Error
    samplingRate: 44100,
    numChannels: 1,
);

record.start(
    path: 'pathTo/file/audio.m4a',
    encoder: AudioEncoder.aacLc,
    bitRate: 32000, // Works!
    samplingRate: 44100,
    numChannels: 1,
);
```

It also worked with `64000` and `128000`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AudioEncoder.aacLc, then don't use 'aac' extension, but use 'm4a'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering here in case anyone has the same issue.
In my case :

- I'm using a file on the device (iOS). (I mean not in remote)
- I'm retrieving the file, and saving it in a local database solution (Isar for me).
- When I'm trying to load the file (with setFilePath or AudioSource.file), it prints the exact same error
- The error came in my case from some transformation that the local database did.. EDIT : Seems that it comes more from iOS only with file_picker (still debugging...), but anyway :

=> to eventually debug this case if every other answers don't work :

**Try to do the very simple test to know if the file you want to load does exist (with File().existsSync() )**

Answer (score -1):

Use 'test.m4a' instead of

`File file = File('test.mp3');`

Comment: Getting: Error loading audio file: (-11829) Cannot Open