# just_audio - "The name 'player' is already defined."

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I am new to flutter and the just_audio package, and am simply trying to reproduce the code on [their website](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio).

**My Goal** - I would like to use this simple AudioPlayer() constructor to get some audio playing on my app with a few lines of code.

**Minimal Code Example** - After adding the following code to the flutter create standard app...

in main.dart

```
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

final player = AudioPlayer();                
final duration = await player.setUrl(           
    'https://example.com/bar.mp3');                    
player.play();
```

and in pubspec.yaml
`just_audio: ^0.9.28`

I get **the following error**

```
Error: Can't use 'player' because it is declared more than once.
```

The app runs when I take these lines out, but I'm not sure why they don't work because they are copy-pasted from the docs.

I searched their github issues and didn't find anything about this, and also didn't find anything already on Stack Overflow.

**To Reproduce**

1. Terminal: flutter create audio_app
2. Terminal: flutter pub add just_audio
3. Copy paste code from  [their website](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) into main.dart -- my code above.

**My Environment**

- Mac OS Big Sur
- Flutter 3.0.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
- Framework • revision f1875d570e (6 weeks ago) • 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
- Engine • revision e85ea0e79c
- Tools • Dart 2.17.6 • DevTools 2.12.2
- just_audio: ^0.9.28
- Testing simulation on Simulator v13.2

Any help understanding what is going on and how to fix it is appreciated.  Let me know if you need me to attach more code.

**Full main.dart file as requested**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

final player = AudioPlayer();                   // Create a player
final duration = await player.setUrl(           // Load a URL
    'http://music.thomasmeli.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Thomas-Meli-Binary-Star-Sample.mp3');                 // Schemes: (https: | file: | asset: )
player.play(); 


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include full main.dart file

Comment: Hi Yeasin - I just did above.  Thanks for checking it out!

Comment: where do you like to play the sound?

Comment: Ideally, I would like the functionality to be independent of what Widget it is in.  I think the documentation says that if you add this code, music should start to play as soon as the app runs.

But if it does need a location just somewhere in the Home MaterialApp scaffolding would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

`player.setUrl` is a future method, while you are using `await` this part needed to be wrapped in `async` function. Or README the just provided the necessary part to play, You can follow [example](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio/example) for better understanding about widget

If you can do on button presses, it will be

on initState

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _playSound();
  }

  _playSound() async {
    final player = AudioPlayer(); // Create a player
    final url =
        'http://music.thomasmeli.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Thomas-Meli-Binary-Star-Sample.mp3';
    await player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(url)));
    await player.play();
  }
```

Try this widget,

```dart
class GA extends StatefulWidget {
  const GA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GA> createState() => _GAState();
}

class _GAState extends State<GA> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _playSound();
  }

  _playSound() async {
    final player = AudioPlayer(); // Create a player
    final url =
        'http://music.thomasmeli.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Thomas-Meli-Binary-Star-Sample.mp3';
    await player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(url)));
    await player.play();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int selected = 1;

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // showContentDialog(context);
          _playSound();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can explore more about how [async-await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) works

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  Unfortunately, I get the following errors when adding the above code in the main() function.

```[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Binding has not yet been initialized.  The "instance" getter on the ServicesBinding binding mixin is only available once that binding has been initialized.```

And

```BindingBase.checkInstance.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/<…>```

and 2 more, but it is too long for a comment, let me know if you want me to attach it to the main thread.

Comment: include `void main() async{WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();...`   I will suggest using last two method

Comment: OK, we're getting closer.  The void main thing still created errors, so I tried your initState code instead.  Now I'm getting this error ```unhandled Exception: (-11800) The operation could not be completed
#0      AudioPlayer._load (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:840:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AudioPlayer._setPlatformActive.setPlatform (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:1421:28)
<asynchronous suspension>```

Comment: Looking at [but doesn't look solved]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786257/just-audio-not-working-on-ios-flutter-unhandled-exception-11800-the-operatio

Comment: Try current one

Comment: Same error: ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: (-11800)

Comment: remove others `player`, save the file, and build again

Comment: As per the documentation - I tried adding

```<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>```

To the plist file, and that didn't do anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "remove others player."  Would you clarify?

Also, should we move this to chat?

Comment: use `home:GA()` widget ,

Comment: I tried looking that up and I'm not sure what that is referring to.  Would you be more specific?  Also, did you get this working on your machine?

Comment: create a new project and try the widget. also you can try `flutter clean` and `flutter upgrade`

Comment: Any way you could include your entire working main.dart file?  I'm confused as to what you are referring to above and haven't gotten it to work yet.